# incrementing the id after adding an entry in mysqldb

Tags: mysql-python

I am trying to write an add entry method but i could get the incrementing of the id to work. It is affecting other methods that i have because when i do a delete, it deletes all entries instead of deleting a specific row. Can you guys help please.

```
def addEntry () :

    #define cursor
    c=db.cursor()

    #execute cursor
    id=c.execute("select max(id)+1 from phones")

    # digs deep to get next id
    id = c.fetchall()[0].values()[0]

    #dosql 
    dosql("insert into phones values (%d,'%s','%s')" % (id,nameVar.get(), phoneVar.get()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the exact problem and only looking at the code you posted, I see a few things.

1. Why you don't use an auto_increment column in MySQL for your 'id' which is the functionality you are trying to implement?
2. I've never seen the following syntax while retrieving rows:

   id = c.fetchall()[0].values()[0]

That line doesn't work for me since c.fetchall()[0] returns a tuple which doesn't have a values method. Since you know the query will only return one row, you can simply do:

```
id = c.fetchone()[0]

or

id, = c.fetchone()
```

3. You are not locking the table so running that code more than once at a time will likely not give you the results you are looking for and you could end up with the same id for 2 rows.